# SSRS custom sort one column ASC and DESC

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

use the attached data set to product SSRS report.
I have been trying to sort the following columns in ascending and descending. Sales_Status column is sorted ascending while the Serial_Number number column needs to be sorted as follows. 
Serial_Number column has a parent group of Sales_Status column
When the  Sales_Status column is “Futures Sales”  I want to sort Serial_Number ascending when is “Past Sales” it should be sorted descending. I have tried different sort order without luck. find attached expected result

---

Tsql query used

```
        DECLARE @SalesTBL TABLE (Department VARCHAR(10), Sales_Status VARCHAR(50), Serial_Number INT);
        INSERT INTO @SalesTBL VALUES
        ('A','Past Sales','3'),('D','Futures Sales','1'),('H','Futures Sales','1'),('L','Past Sales','3'),
        ('H','Past Sales','5'),('D','Past Sales','1'),('L','Past Sales','2'),('B','Futures Sales','6'),
        ('P','Past Sales','5'),('A','Past Sales','4'),('Q','Past Sales','1'),('D','Past Sales','6'),
        ('D','Past Sales','6'),('O','Past Sales','4'),('I','Past Sales','5'),('Q','Past Sales','4'),
        ('F','Past Sales','2'),('N','Past Sales','5'),('H','Past Sales','1'),('H','Past Sales','3'),
        ('P','Past Sales','3'),('H','Past Sales','4'),('B','Past Sales','4'),('L','Past Sales','5'),
        ('H','Past Sales','5'),('Q','Past Sales','5'),('H','Past Sales','4'),('D','Past Sales','2'),
        ('k','Past Sales','2'),('H','Past Sales','3'),('E','Past Sales','2'),('F','Past Sales','2'),
        ('D','Past Sales','3'),('R','Past Sales','4'),('D','Past Sales','3'),('L','Past Sales','2'),
        ('M','Futures Sales','6'),('I','Futures Sales','3'),('D','Past Sales','1'),('A','Futures Sales','1'),
        ('E','Futures Sales','3'),('A','Past Sales','5'),('L','Past Sales','6'),('F','Past Sales','3'),
        ('O','Past Sales','4'),('H','Past Sales','4'),('D','Past Sales','3'),('F','Past Sales','1'),
        ('A','Past Sales','6'),('U','Past Sales','6'),('H','Past Sales','2'),('F','Past Sales','4'),
        ('R','Past Sales','6'),('O','Past Sales','5'),('E','Past Sales','1'),('H','Past Sales','6'),
        ('B','Past Sales','4'),('H','Past Sales','6'),('H','Past Sales','5'),('N','Past Sales','1'),
        ('O','Past Sales','6'),('Q','Past Sales','2'),('A','Past Sales','5'),('I','Past Sales','4'),
        ('H','Past Sales','5'),('L','Futures Sales','6'),('k','Past Sales','1'),('H','Past Sales','4'),
        ('N','Futures Sales','4'),('k','Past Sales','4'),('O','Past Sales','2'),('F','Past Sales','4'),
        ('Q','Past Sales','4'),('A','Past Sales','1'),('L','Past Sales','4'),('A','Past Sales','3'),
        ('F','Past Sales','3'),('K','Past Sales','2'),('H','Past Sales','5'),('B','Past Sales','4'),
        ('O','Past Sales','1'),('O','Past Sales','1'),('H','Past Sales','6'),('F','Past Sales','4'),
        ('k','Past Sales','1'),('T','Past Sales','6'),('D','Past Sales','4'),('R','Past Sales','4'),
        ('B','Past Sales','6'),('H','Past Sales','4'),('A','Past Sales','2'),('B','Past Sales','2'),
        ('H','Past Sales','2'),('H','Past Sales','3'),('F','Past Sales','1'),('F','Futures Sales','3'),
        ('H','Past Sales','1'),('H','Futures Sales','6'),('H','Past Sales','5'),('N','Past Sales','2'),
        ('R','Futures Sales','3'),('H','Past Sales','2'),('E','Futures Sales','5'),
        ('F','Past Sales','5'),('D','Past Sales','4'),('H','Past Sales','6'),('H','Futures Sales','2'),
        ('B','Past Sales','6'),('K','Past Sales','1'),('N','Past Sales','2'),('D','Past Sales','2'),
        ('W','Past Sales','2'),('S','Futures Sales','2'),('H','Past Sales','1'),('E','Past Sales','6'),
        ('E','Past Sales','5'),('N','Past Sales','6'),('k','Past Sales','5'),('S','Past Sales','1'),
        ('O','Past Sales','4'),('Q','Past Sales','6'),('F','Past Sales','2'),('O','Past Sales','4'),
        ('B','Past Sales','5'),('K','Futures Sales','4'),('F','Past Sales','6'),('A','Past Sales','4'),
        ('N','Past Sales','5'),('B','Past Sales','1'),('S','Past Sales','3'),('H','Past Sales','6'),
        ('L','Past Sales','6'),('O','Past Sales','5'),('H','Past Sales','6'),('R','Past Sales','4'),
        ('k','Past Sales','5'),('H','Past Sales','3'),('F','Past Sales','1'),('A','Futures Sales','1'),
        ('F','Past Sales','4'),('B','Past Sales','5'),('k','Past Sales','4'),('D','Past Sales','5'),
        ('B','Past Sales','2'),('k','Past Sales','1'),('L','Past Sales','4'),('B','Past Sales','4'),
        ('I','Past Sales','5'),('H','Past Sales','1'),('K','Past Sales','3'),('E','Past Sales','4'),
        ('E','Past Sales','1'),('A','Past Sales','6'),('A','Past Sales','4'),('k','Past Sales','6'),
        ('A','Past Sales','3'),('A','Past Sales','2'),('H','Futures Sales','4'),
        ('W','Past Sales','3'),('Q','Past Sales','1'),('k','Past Sales','5'),('S','Past Sales','1'),
        ('Q','Past Sales','5'),('H','Past Sales','4'),('V','Past Sales','6'),('N','Past Sales','6'),
        ('H','Past Sales','2'),('k','Past Sales','1'),('H','Past Sales','3'),('K','Futures Sales','1'),
        ('H','Past Sales','1'),('H','Past Sales','3'),('K','Past Sales','1'),('D','Past Sales','5'),
        ('B','Past Sales','6'),('N','Past Sales','3'),('B','Past Sales','3'),('O','Past Sales','3'),
        ('D','Past Sales','5'),('A','Past Sales','5'),('F','Past Sales','4'),('A','Past Sales','4'),
        ('F','Past Sales','3'),('J','Past Sales','6'),('k','Past Sales','3'),('H','Past Sales','3'),
        ('E','Past Sales','4'),('A','Past Sales','1'),('H','Past Sales','2'),('F','Past Sales','1'),
        ('K','Past Sales','5'),('B','Past Sales','2'),('E','Past Sales','4'),('B','Past Sales','6'),
        ('L','Past Sales','4'),('T','Past Sales','3'),('H','Past Sales','6'),('k','Futures Sales','4'),
        ('H','Past Sales','1'),('D','Futures Sales','3'),('M','Past Sales','5'),('L','Past Sales','2'),
        ('O','Past Sales','2'),('B','Past Sales','1'),('k','Past Sales','1'),('F','Past Sales','2'),
        ('E','Past Sales','1'),('N','Past Sales','5'),('B','Past Sales','5'),('H','Past Sales','2'),
        ('F','Past Sales','6'),('k','Past Sales','2'),('M','Past Sales','1'),('K','Past Sales','1'),
        ('H','Past Sales','4'),('N','Past Sales','4'),('M','Past Sales','1'),('H','Past Sales','2'),
        ('D','Futures Sales','6'),('F','Past Sales','2'),('S','Past Sales','3'),
        ('T','Past Sales','1'),('N','Past Sales','3'),('D','Past Sales','3'),('O','Past Sales','2'),
        ('P','Past Sales','6'),('k','Past Sales','3'),('L','Past Sales','6'),('H','Past Sales','6'),
        ('F','Past Sales','3'),('A','Past Sales','6'),('k','Past Sales','4'),('Q','Past Sales','1'),
        ('Q','Futures Sales','4'),('Q','Past Sales','5'),('O','Past Sales','5'),
        ('T','Past Sales','2'),('L','Past Sales','5'),('B','Past Sales','6'),('L','Past Sales','4'),
        ('S','Past Sales','4'),('K','Futures Sales','2'),('D','Past Sales','6'),('O','Past Sales','3'),
        ('B','Past Sales','6'),('H','Past Sales','4'),('H','Past Sales','2'),('F','Past Sales','2'),
        ('A','Past Sales','4'),('B','Past Sales','6'),('F','Past Sales','4'),('K','Past Sales','1'),
        ('A','Past Sales','6'),('L','Past Sales','5'),('O','Past Sales','4'),('B','Futures Sales','5'),
        ('S','Past Sales','5'),('B','Futures Sales','2'),('k','Past Sales','5'),('A','Past Sales','6'),
        ('k','Past Sales','3'),('H','Past Sales','3'),('Q','Past Sales','1'),('H','Past Sales','3'),
        ('T','Past Sales','6'),('R','Past Sales','6'),('B','Past Sales','5'),('U','Past Sales','5'),
        ('K','Past Sales','2'),('B','Futures Sales','2'),('B','Past Sales','3'),('F','Past Sales','5'),
        ('L','Past Sales','5'),('k','Past Sales','3'),('O','Past Sales','6'),('H','Past Sales','2'),
        ('L','Past Sales','5'),('T','Past Sales','6'),('E','Past Sales','3'),
        ('L','Past Sales','2'),('B','Futures Sales','5'),('F','Past Sales','2'),('D','Past Sales','3'),
        ('N','Past Sales','3');
 SELECT * FROM @SalesTBL
```

OutPut

[image]

Comment: Please remove the spaces before `[1]` in your very last line, so that your image will render.

Comment: In your script the Serial_Number is declared INT but in the table insert, serial numbers are inside quotation marks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the serial number group you will set two sorting expressions:

An ascending on

`=Iif(Fields!Sales_Status.Value="Past Sales", Fields!Serial_Number.Value,"")`

A descending on

`=Iif(Fields!Sales_Status.Value="Future Sales", Fields!Serial_Number.Value,"")`

[image]

[image]